# Can't record new track in audacity with pulseaudio

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm trying to record audio from my mic with audacity. From version 2.2.0 when you hit record button it appends recording to existing track, so I figured out that by pressing Shift-R it records to a new track (old default behaviour), but that isn't working with pulseaudio for some reason (gives some message about latency first time you try and then just doesn't do anything at all).

I've removed pulseaudio and without it it works just fine, but firefox isn't working without pulseaudio.

Is there a way to either make audacity to work with pulseaudio or firefox to work with alsa?